# "Leave a comment" link even when you can't

Tags: comments

On http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/page/7/ I disabled 
comments for "USDCAD options vs CADUSD options arbitrage?", but it 
still has a "Leave a Comment" link.

Clicking the link takes you to 
http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/2011/02/25/usdcad-options-vs-cadusd-options-arbitrage-2/#respond 
where it, of course, shows that you can't leave a comment.

The timeline page correctly does not show the 'comment' link: http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/2011/02/

How to fix?

Comment: What Theme are you using?

Comment: Ahh, I see: TwentyTen. Just a minute; fix coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `loop.php` template file, you will find this line:

```
<span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></span>
```

If you don't want "leave a comment" to display if comments are closed, you can wrap the call to `comments_popup_link()` in a `if ( comments_open() )` conditional, like such:

```
<span class="comments-link"><?php if ( comments_open() ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></span>
```

Note: you may also want to check the other `loop-foobar.php` template files.

Comment: This did the trick, once I realized that line appears in loop.php 3 times!

Comment: Might be a good idea to use a child theme to avoid losing changes in future versions.

Comment: Always a good reminder, John. I generally assume that a Child Theme will be the method of implementation, but that might not always be a valid assumption. :)